# ¿Cómo hacer un "Game Over" y que vuelva a empezar de nuevo el juego?

Tags: game, libgdx

Estoy intentando programar un videojuego del estilo Endless Running en **Android Studio** con **libGDX** y me he encontrado con un problema en el que llevo tiempo estancado, una vez detecta el juego la colisión, el juego pasa a estado de "Game Over" pero no soy capaz de hacer que vuelva a estado de inicio para reiniciar el juego. Otro error que me he encontrado ha sido que no consigo hacer desaparecer las monedas cuando el personaje colisiona con ellas, aunque este es un error menor.

```
 package es.rodriguez.dinojump;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.RETURN;

public class Game extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;

    //Fondos
    Texture background;
    Texture background2;
    int bg2altura = 200;//altura del suelo

    //Dinosaurio
    Texture[] dinos;
    float velocity = -30;
    float gravity = 2;
    float impulse = -30;
    float dinoY;
    int dinoAnim = 0;
    int salto = 0;
    Rectangle dinoR;

    //Bomba y moneda
    Texture bomb;
    Rectangle bombR;

    Texture coin;
    Rectangle coinR;

    float objectVelocity = 10;
    int numberOfObjects = 4;
    float[] objectX = new float[numberOfObjects];
    float distanceBetweenObjects;

    GameState gameState = GameState.TAP_TO_PLAY;


    //private ShapeRenderer shrend;
    //private boolean debug;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        SoundManager.loadSFX();

        background = new Texture("bg.png");
        background2 = new Texture("bg2.jpg");

        //Dino
        dinos = new Texture[5];
        dinos[0] = new Texture("frame-1.png");
        dinos[1] = new Texture("frame-2.png");
        dinos[2] = new Texture("frame-3.png");
        dinos[3] = new Texture("frame-4.png");
        dinos[4] = new Texture("dizzy-1.png");
        dinoY = (bg2altura);

        dinoR = new Rectangle(dinos[0].getWidth() / 2F, dinoY, dinos[0].getWidth() / 2, dinos[0].getHeight() / 2);

        //Bombas y monedas
        bomb = new Texture("bomb.png");
        bombR = new Rectangle();

        coin = new Texture("coin.png");
        coinR = new Rectangle();

        distanceBetweenObjects = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 3 / 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
            objectX[i] = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() + i * distanceBetweenObjects;
        }

        /*
        //Para testear
        shrend = new ShapeRenderer();
        debug = true;*/
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        switch(gameState) {

            case TAP_TO_PLAY:
                if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

                    gameState = GameState.PLAY;
                    salto += 1;
                    SoundManager.play(SFX.JUMP);
                }
                break;

            case PLAY:

                SoundManager.play(SFX.GAME);

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {

                    if (objectX[i] < -bomb.getWidth()) {
                        objectX[i] = objectX[i] + numberOfObjects * distanceBetweenObjects;
                    }
                    objectX[i] = objectX[i] - objectVelocity;
                }

                if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
                    if (salto < 2) { //
                        salto += 1;
                        SoundManager.play(SFX.JUMP);
                        velocity = impulse;
                    }
                } else {
                    velocity = velocity + gravity;
                    dinoR.y -= velocity;
                }
                //Para que no pase para abajo del suelo
                if (dinoR.y < bg2altura) {
                    dinoR.y = bg2altura;
                    salto = 0;
                }
                //Animar el dinosaurio
                if (dinoAnim == 3) {
                    dinoAnim = 0;
                } else {
                    dinoAnim += 1;
                }
                break;

            case GAME_OVER:

                if (dinoR.overlaps(bombR)) {

                    gameState = gameState.TAP_TO_PLAY; //falta reiniciar juego

                }

                if(dinoR.overlaps(coinR)){
                    SoundManager.play(SFX.SCORE);

                }



                    //Falta reiniciar juego


                break;
        }

        batch.begin();

        batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        batch.draw(background2, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), bg2altura);

        batch.draw(dinos[dinoAnim], dinoR.x, dinoR.y,dinos[0].getWidth()/2, dinos[0].getHeight()/2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            bombR = new Rectangle(objectX[i], bg2altura, bomb.getWidth()/2, bomb.getHeight()/2);
            batch.draw(bomb, bombR.x, bombR.y, bomb.getWidth(), bomb.getHeight());


            coinR = new Rectangle(objectX[i], bg2altura+coin.getHeight()*3,coin.getWidth()/2, coin.getHeight()/2);
            batch.draw(coin, coinR.x, coinR.y, coinR.width, coinR.height);

             if (dinoR.overlaps(bombR)) {

                SoundManager.play(SFX.HIT);
                dinos[dinoAnim] = dinos[4];
                SoundManager.hitSFX.dispose();
                SoundManager.gameSFX.stop();
                gameState = gameState.GAME_OVER; //falta reiniciar juego

            }else if(dinoR.overlaps(coinR)){
                SoundManager.play(SFX.SCORE);

                //Falta contador de monedas, arreglar o sonido
            }
        }
        batch.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        background.dispose();
        background2.dispose();
       // shrend.dispose();
    }
}
```

El código es mejorable pero estoy empezando.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## **Alternativa 1**

Puedes encapsular todo el codigo que tienes en esa clase y luego reiniciar llamando `new Game()` me explico...

Constaría de 3 clases diferentes

- `Assets` la cual manejará todos los `Disposables`. Separando esto
  evitaras crearlos cada vez que llamemos `new Game()`
- `GameManager` esta es la clase principal, la cual extiende `ApplicationAdapter` esta clase se encargará de crear un nuevo juego y renderizar el mismo.
- `Game` la cual manejara toda la lógica del juego.

**Assets**

```
public class Assets {
    public Texture background;
    public Texture background2;
    public Texture dinos = new Texture[5];
    public Texture bomb;
    public Texture coin;
    public Texture shrend;

    public Assets(){
        SoundManager.loadSFX();

        background = new Texture("bg.png");
        background2 = new Texture("bg2.jpg");
        dinos[0] = new Texture("frame-1.png");
        dinos[1] = new Texture("frame-2.png");
        dinos[2] = new Texture("frame-3.png");
        dinos[3] = new Texture("frame-4.png");
        dinos[4] = new Texture("dizzy-1.png");
        bomb = new Texture("bomb.png");
        coin = new Texture("coin.png");
        shrend = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    public void dispose(){
        for(Texture t: dinos)
            t.dispose();

        background.dispose();
        background2.dispose();
        bomb.dispose();
        coin.dispose();
        shrend.dispose();
    }
}
```

**GameManager**

```
public class GameManager extends ApplicationAdapter { // OJO ESTA ES LA CLASE PRINCIPAL, LA UNICA QUE EXTIENDE `ApplicationAdapter`

    private Assets assets;
    private batch;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        assets = new Assets();
        game = new Game(assets);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        game.render(batch);

        if(game.gameState == GameState.GAME_OVER)
            game = new Game(assets);// aqui reseteas el juego


    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        assets.dispose();
    }
}
```

**Game**

```
public class Game {

    //Fondos
    int bg2altura = 200;//altura del suelo
    float velocity = -30;
    float gravity = 2;
    float impulse = -30;
    float dinoY;
    int dinoAnim = 0;
    int salto = 0;

    Rectangle dinoR;
    Rectangle bombR;
    Rectangle coinR;

    float objectVelocity = 10;
    int numberOfObjects = 4;
    float[] objectX = new float[numberOfObjects];
    float distanceBetweenObjects;

    public GameState gameState = GameState.TAP_TO_PLAY;
    private Assets assets;

    //private ShapeRenderer shrend;
    //private boolean debug;


    public Game(Assets assets) {
        this.assets = assets;

        dinoY = (bg2altura);
        dinoR = new Rectangle(assets.dinos[0].getWidth() / 2F, dinoY, assets.dinos[0].getWidth() / 2, assets.dinos[0].getHeight() / 2);

        //Bombas y monedas
        bombR = new Rectangle();
        coinR = new Rectangle();

        distanceBetweenObjects = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 3 / 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
            objectX[i] = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() + i * distanceBetweenObjects;
        }

        /*
        //Para testear
        shrend = new ShapeRenderer();
        debug = true;*/
    }

    public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
        switch(gameState) {

            case TAP_TO_PLAY:
                if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

                    gameState = GameState.PLAY;
                    salto += 1;
                    SoundManager.play(SFX.JUMP);
                }
                break;

            case PLAY:

                SoundManager.play(SFX.GAME);

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {

                    if (objectX[i] < -bomb.getWidth()) {
                        objectX[i] = objectX[i] + numberOfObjects * distanceBetweenObjects;
                    }
                    objectX[i] = objectX[i] - objectVelocity;
                }

                if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
                    if (salto < 2) { //
                        salto += 1;
                        SoundManager.play(SFX.JUMP);
                        velocity = impulse;
                    }
                } else {
                    velocity = velocity + gravity;
                    dinoR.y -= velocity;
                }
                //Para que no pase para abajo del suelo
                if (dinoR.y < bg2altura) {
                    dinoR.y = bg2altura;
                    salto = 0;
                }
                //Animar el dinosaurio
                if (dinoAnim == 3) {
                    dinoAnim = 0;
                } else {
                    dinoAnim += 1;
                }
                break;
            // ESTO ES REDUDANTE, ahora `GameManager` se encarga de este caso
            //case GAME_OVER:

            //  if (dinoR.overlaps(bombR)) {

            //      gameState = gameState.TAP_TO_PLAY; //falta reiniciar juego

            //  }

            //  if(dinoR.overlaps(coinR)){
            //      SoundManager.play(SFX.SCORE);

            //  }



                //Falta reiniciar juego


            //  break;
        }

        batch.begin();

        batch.draw(assets.background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        batch.draw(assets.background2, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), bg2altura);

        batch.draw(assets.dinos[dinoAnim], dinoR.x, dinoR.y,assets.dinos[0].getWidth()/2, assets.dinos[0].getHeight()/2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            bombR = new Rectangle(objectX[i], bg2altura, assets.bomb.getWidth()/2, assets.bomb.getHeight()/2);
            batch.draw(assets.bomb, bombR.x, bombR.y, assets.bomb.getWidth(), assets.bomb.getHeight());


            coinR = new Rectangle(objectX[i], bg2altura+assets.coin.getHeight()*3,assets.coin.getWidth()/2, assets.coin.getHeight()/2);
            batch.draw(assets.coin, coinR.x, coinR.y, coinR.width, coinR.height);

            if (dinoR.overlaps(bombR)) {

                SoundManager.play(SFX.HIT);
                assets.dinos[dinoAnim] = dinos[4];
                SoundManager.hitSFX.dispose();
                SoundManager.gameSFX.stop();
                gameState = gameState.GAME_OVER; //falta reiniciar juego, ya no.

            }else if(dinoR.overlaps(coinR)){
                SoundManager.play(SFX.SCORE);

                //Falta contador de monedas, arreglar o sonido
            }
        }
        batch.end();

    }
}
```

Notas:

- `case GAME_OVER` ahora es redundante,este caso lo maneja `GameManager`
- `new Rectangle()` en render es mala idea, la creación de este objeto a 60 veces por segundo puede ser abrumador para el Heap, en lugar de esto puedes utilizar `bombR.set(...);`

## **Alternativa 2**

Otra manera y probablemente la mas simple pero menos elegante es reiniciar todas las variables a su estado original

```
public void reset(){
   //aqui reinicias todas las variables a su estado original.
   dinoY = (bg2altura);
   ... etc ect 
}
```

y se veria asi...

```
public class Game extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;

    //Fondos
    Texture background;
    Texture background2;
    int bg2altura = 200;//altura del suelo

    //Dinosaurio
    Texture[] dinos;
    float velocity = -30;
    float gravity = 2;
    float impulse = -30;
    float dinoY;
    int dinoAnim = 0;
    int salto = 0;
    Rectangle dinoR;

    //Bomba y moneda
    Texture bomb;
    Rectangle bombR;

    Texture coin;
    Rectangle coinR;

    float objectVelocity = 10;
    int numberOfObjects = 4;
    float[] objectX = new float[numberOfObjects];
    float distanceBetweenObjects;

    GameState gameState;


    //private ShapeRenderer shrend;
    //private boolean debug;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        SoundManager.loadSFX();

        background = new Texture("bg.png");
        background2 = new Texture("bg2.jpg");
        dinos = new Texture[5];
        dinos[0] = new Texture("frame-1.png");
        dinos[1] = new Texture("frame-2.png");
        dinos[2] = new Texture("frame-3.png");
        dinos[3] = new Texture("frame-4.png");
        dinos[4] = new Texture("dizzy-1.png");
        bomb = new Texture("bomb.png");
        coin = new Texture("coin.png");

        reset();

        /*
        //Para testear
        shrend = new ShapeRenderer();
        debug = true;*/
    }

    public void reset(){
        //TODO todas las variables que cambien se resetean al estado original.
        gameState = GameState.TAP_TO_PLAY;
        velocity = -30;
        gravity = 2;
        impulse = -30;
        dinoY;
        dinoAnim = 0;
        salto = 0;
        bg2altura = 200;

        dinoY = (bg2altura);
        dinoR = new Rectangle(dinos[0].getWidth() / 2F, dinoY, dinos[0].getWidth() / 2, dinos[0].getHeight() / 2);
        bombR = new Rectangle();
        coinR = new Rectangle();

        distanceBetweenObjects = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 3 / 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
            objectX[i] = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() + i * distanceBetweenObjects;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        switch(gameState) {

            case TAP_TO_PLAY:
                if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

                    gameState = GameState.PLAY;
                    salto += 1;
                    SoundManager.play(SFX.JUMP);
                }
                break;

            case PLAY:

                SoundManager.play(SFX.GAME);

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {

                    if (objectX[i] < -bomb.getWidth()) {
                        objectX[i] = objectX[i] + numberOfObjects * distanceBetweenObjects;
                    }
                    objectX[i] = objectX[i] - objectVelocity;
                }

                if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
                    if (salto < 2) { //
                        salto += 1;
                        SoundManager.play(SFX.JUMP);
                        velocity = impulse;
                    }
                } else {
                    velocity = velocity + gravity;
                    dinoR.y -= velocity;
                }
                //Para que no pase para abajo del suelo
                if (dinoR.y < bg2altura) {
                    dinoR.y = bg2altura;
                    salto = 0;
                }
                //Animar el dinosaurio
                if (dinoAnim == 3) {
                    dinoAnim = 0;
                } else {
                    dinoAnim += 1;
                }
                break;

            case GAME_OVER:

                if (dinoR.overlaps(bombR)) {

                    gameState = gameState.TAP_TO_PLAY; //falta reiniciar juego

                }

                if(dinoR.overlaps(coinR)){
                    SoundManager.play(SFX.SCORE);

                }



                //Falta reiniciar juego


                break;
        }

        batch.begin();

        batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        batch.draw(background2, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), bg2altura);

        batch.draw(dinos[dinoAnim], dinoR.x, dinoR.y,dinos[0].getWidth()/2, dinos[0].getHeight()/2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            bombR = new Rectangle(objectX[i], bg2altura, bomb.getWidth()/2, bomb.getHeight()/2);
            batch.draw(bomb, bombR.x, bombR.y, bomb.getWidth(), bomb.getHeight());


            coinR = new Rectangle(objectX[i], bg2altura+coin.getHeight()*3,coin.getWidth()/2, coin.getHeight()/2);
            batch.draw(coin, coinR.x, coinR.y, coinR.width, coinR.height);

            if (dinoR.overlaps(bombR)) {

                SoundManager.play(SFX.HIT);
                dinos[dinoAnim] = dinos[4];
                SoundManager.hitSFX.dispose();
                SoundManager.gameSFX.stop();
                reset();//TODO falta reiniciar juego, ya NO.


            }else if(dinoR.overlaps(coinR)){
                SoundManager.play(SFX.SCORE);

                //Falta contador de monedas, arreglar o sonido
            }
        }
        batch.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        background.dispose();
        background2.dispose();
        // shrend.dispose();
    }
}
```

## **Eliminar monedas**

Una idea mas organizada para dejar de dibujar o renderizar las monedas seria utilizando OOP

Creas una clase `Coin`, en la clase `Game` haces un `Array<Coin>` que contiene todas las monedas, con un loop dibujas todas las monedas de ese `Array<Coin>` tan pronto el jugador colisione con una moneda, quitas la moneda del array `coins.removeValue(coin,false);`

```
public class Coin extends Rectangle{ //Nota que extiende la clase Rectangle para que podamos utilizar .overlaps y las variable x,y,width,height para dibujar
   public Texture texture;

   public Coin(Texture texture,float x,float y,float width, float height){
       this.texture = texture;
       set(x,y,width,height);
   }

   public void render(SpriteBatch batch){
       batch.draw(texture,x,y,width,height);
   }
}
```

```
public class Game{
   ...
   ...
   Array<Coin> coins = new Array<Coin>();

   public Game(){
     ...
     ...
     //a~ade las monedas que quieras
     coins.add(new Coin(assets.coin,0,0,10,10));
     coins.add(new Coin(assets.coin,100,0,10,10));
     coins.add(new Coin(assets.coin,200,0,10,10));
   }

   public void render(){
     ...
     batch.begin();
     for(Coin coin: coins){
         coin.render(batch); //dibujas la moneda
         if(dinoR.overlaps(coin)){
             //se ha capturado una moneda
             monedasCapturadas++;
             coins.removeValue(coin,false); //quitas la moneda del array
         }
     }
     batch.end();

   }
}
```